# How to group objects in a list with object property in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, hashmap, java-stream

How to **group** all the Objects in a List with the **same Object property?** Without mentioning the Object property value.

**Model Class:**

```
public class Item {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String team
}
```

`List<item> items = new ArrayList();`

**I have tried this:**

```
items.stream().filter(item -> "Elites".equals(item.team)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this requires passing the team name as a parameter.

How can we group the items without specifying a team value?

And Making a **HashMap** with **Key** as the ***item. team*** and **value** as a ***list of key-value pairs with that team.name & item.id***

**Like this:**

```
"item.team":{
    "item.id":"item.name",
    "item.id":"item.name",
    "item.id":"item.name",
    .....
}
```

Comment: If we want to have a `List`, then I am not sure this is possible. Would it be feasible to transform the `List` into a `Map<String, List<Item>>`, where the key is the type (as `String`) and the vallue is a `List` of all `Item`s of this type?

Comment: @Turing85  Yes that would suffice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we can return a `Map<String, List<Item>>`, where the key is the `team` and the value is a `List<Item>` belonging to that team, we can use

```
final Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByTeam = 
    items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.team));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Ch642S)

Remark: This solution was first posted in a comment by another user and they deleted the comment shortly after. I do not remember the user's name. If they post an answer, I will delete mine. If they do not want to post an answer, but contact me, I will credit them by name.

A comment on the code: I would recommend to introduce getters for the attributes since the `stream`-operation is most likely to be called outside of class `Item` itself, hence attribute `team` will not be visible. Also, this would lead to an implementation like

```
final Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByTeam = 
    items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getTeam));
```

which may or may not be regarded as "more pleasing" to the reader.

Comment: In my case `Map<String, List<Item>>` gave an error. Where I replaced it with `Map<Object, List<Item>> itemsByTeam`

Comment: @Lenzman [I cannot reproduce the problem you described.](https://ideone.com/Ch642S)

Comment: Yeah now working for me. Eclipse gave me an error and suggested making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

From the accepted answer by [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85).

I have created a **complete solution** for the **Question** I asked.

**To create an output with the following structure:**

```
"item.team":{
    "item.id":"item.name",
    "item.id":"item.name",
    "item.id":"item.name",
    .....
}
```

**Source data:**

```
List<Item> itemsListData = //Get the data
```

**Function to group the Items:**

```
public static Map<String, List<Item>> groupItemsByTeam(Collection<Item> itemsList) {
    return itemsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::team));
}
```

**Structure the items list returned by *groupItemsByTeam*:**

```
//GET THE GROUPED DATA
Map<String, List<Item>> result = groupItemsByTeam(itemsListData);

//STRUCTURE THE GROUPED DATA
for (Entry<String, List<Item>> parentItem : result .entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(parentItem .getKey() + " : "); // item.team value

    for (Item childItem : parentItem.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(childItem.getKEY() + " = " + childItem.getVALUE());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Team A : 
Item 1= Item 1 name
Item 2= Item 2 name
-------------------------------------------
Team G : 
Item 456= Item 456 name
Item 254= Item 254 name
-------------------------------------------
```

[Reference from baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)